# How to upload the Images in one drive (excel) to Power apps?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to create an app with the  list of items and their images. I have saved the Images in a folder in one drive and created and excel in one drive with four columns (product id, product name, dimensions, and Image path) , please check the below image. However, when I upload the data and gave the data source it is not displaying the image in the layout. Is it because the path format is not correct? Please check the below image and let me know where I am doing wrong. I need the Image to be displayed, I have checked many forums but could not find the solution.

[image]

Please check the below powerapp screenshot as you can see I have given the correct data souce[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show the formula that feeds the gallary?

Comment: @MarkS. Please check the screenshots in the question, I have updated it. I entered the formula ThisItem.ProductImage. Product Image is the table name. You can see the table screenshot as well in the question . Do you think the the format of the image in the excel is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Per my test, when we connect the data source with an excel table in onedrive,make sure the Image value is map to the related excel table column as shown  below:

[image]

More information for your reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/add-images-pictures-audio-video#add-images-from-the-cloud-to-your-app

**----------------------------Update:-------------------------------------**

To avoid error, you could copy the direct link of the image in details panel:

[image]

Comment: I followed the same procedure mentioned in the given link but still am not able to fetch the images. Could you please once again look at the screenshots in the question and tell me if the format of the path for the images that I have mentioned in the excel is correct. I have saved Images in the one drive as well.

Comment: @RevanErraboina you did the syntax identical to here? In your images it says `ThisItem.ProductImage`, whereas Julie_MSFT has `ThisItem.Image`

Comment: @MarkS. Image is a Table name in Julie's link. In my workbook, the table name is ProductImage

Comment: I have updated the reply, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issues but have noticed the location of the excel file matters.  Even if the links in it are the same value.  Lets say my file is located in a teams folder in the general tab it works and the photo is displayed.  If I move the file to a teams channel although all the other fields display the photo is a white square.
Try moving the file, then reconnecting the file in the new location.  Yow will get another data source with _1 which you can then select as the gallery data source.